# ZFS mount dataset for zone

Tags: solaris, zfs, solaris-zones

I shutdown my non-global zone and umount her point zfs zonepath.

command for umount:

```
zfs unmount -f zones-pool/one-zone
```

details:

```
zfs list | grep one
zones-pool/one-zone                                  15,2G  9,82G    32K  /zones-fs/one-zone
zones-pool/one/rpool/ROOT/solaris               15,2G  9,82G  7,83G  /zones-fs/one/root
```

in the above, it is seen that there is an occupied space, 9.82G of 15.2G

more details:

```
# zfs get mountpoint zones-pool/one-zone
NAME                       PROPERTY    VALUE                      SOURCE
zones-pool/one-zone        mountpoint  /zones-fs/one-zone          local

# zfs get mounted zones-pool/one-zone
NAME                       PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
zones-pool/one-zone         mounted   no     -
but, if I try mount point zfs
```

I can not see the content

step 1 mount:

```
zfs mount zones-pool/one-zone
```

step 2 see mount with df -h:

```
df -h | grep one
zones-pool/one-zone/rpool/ROOT/solaris    25G    32K       9,8G     1%    /zones-fs/one-zone/root
zones-pool/one-zone    25G    32K       9,8G     1%    /zones-fs/one-zone
```

step 3 list content:

```
ls -l /zones-fs/one-zone/root
total 0
```

why?

also in step 2, you see that df -h prints 1% used

I do not understand

Comment: try do do:

`zoneadm -z nameofyourzone attach -a`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I completely follow what you're trying to do.  But you also don't show any output for your zone's config, or even the version of Solaris (10 or 11?).  And I can't tell if you're trying to do something for a zone called one or called one-zone.

For starters maybe post:  `zoneadm list -iv` which may also give us the state of your zones.  And toss in a `svcs -x` for good measure.

And my guess as to why you may be seeing things that you're not expecting to see is that you ran your `zfs unmount` command with a -f to force the unmount.  So something was probably using the mount, and perhaps also preventing you to be able to remount.